# Building a .net application on classic ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic, session-state, cross-application

We have a big classic ASP website, and we want to start writing new code in .net, (the website is way to big to rewrite 100% at this stage).

The old website uses session variables, will these still be accessible in the .net pages, and if not (which I suspect) is there anything we can do to make them accessible?

The new section is detachable, that is it is pretty much independent from the rest of the site so should be fine to write in .NET, it's just sessions which are important to us.  Do we need another login page?

How bad practise would it be to ajax a local .net page which sets session info when they login to the old site?  Can we copy session data this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to Share Session State Between Classic ASP and ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx) (MSDN)

SO topics:

[Classic ASP to ASP.Net one-off session data copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526844/classic-asp-to-asp-net-one-off-session-data-copy)

[Classic ASP and ASP.NET Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133173/classic-asp-and-asp-net-integration)